# Serve file using nginx web server

Tags: nginx, http

Hi I have static file (song.mp3 under /song directory in the VM) that I would like to serve under path `/song` using nginx web server. If anybody visits the path in browser, the file should start downloading.

I added the following info in the config file

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /song {
        root /song/song.mp3;
    }
}
```

However when I start the nginx service and use the path `http://localhost/song` it throws 404 not Found. Any pointers on what might be causing this?

Comment: Did you check the logs for any errors?

Comment: @rvs This is the error: 
023/04/01 13:47:37 [error] 23#23: *2 open() "/song/song.mp3/song" failed (20: Not a directory), client: localhost, server: localhost, request: "GET /song HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try the following below

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /
    {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /song/
    {
        try_files $uri /song/$uri;
    }
}
```

Try to use **try_files**. The **$uri** will map /song/ directory with /song/ & when you will hit the url **http://localhost/song/song.mp3** it will start download.

Also make sure **song.mp3** exists in `/usr/share/nginx/html/song` folder.